# How to rollback one particular commit in Git?

Tags: git

Here's my situation:

1. About 10 commits ago, I accidentally did a bad commit. I was switching between UNIX/Windows, and long story short, I did a commit where EVERY file was changed, due to the line endings.
2. I had done about 10 commits after that.
3. I now realize that in order to PUSH to the remote repository, I need to undo the commit from step (1) (there's a setting in `.gitattributes` which I've modified for this to normalize).

How do I go back to that point in time and not commit every file? And then I need to re-commit the other 9 changes after that?

Comment: Have you pushed the 10 commits to your remote yet? Is your remote private or shared/public? This is important.

Comment: Also, have you read the [free online Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book)? There's a section that talks specifically about [rewriting your history](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History). I also recommend chapters 1-3, and 6-6.5. Learn how to rebase, both interactively and non-interactively.

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't pushed your 10 commits yet, or your remote repo is private and not shared with other people, then you can try using an interactive rebase:

```bash
$ git rebase -i head~10 # Go back 10 commits in time.
```

In the TODO list of commits, choose `edit` for the one at the top of the list:

```
edit d6627aa Commit message 1
pick 0efdaca Commit message 2
pick 9ec752f Commit message 3
pick c84bf57 Commit message 4
pick d4bcd50 Commit message 5
pick c0110c9 Commit message 6
pick 6606d13 Commit message 7
pick 22933be Commit message 8
pick cab2453 Commit message 9
pick 05add41 Commit message 10
```

Then amend your last commit to change the line endings to be however you want:

```bash
# Modify your .gitattributes, then amend last commit
$ git commit --amend
$ git rebase --continue
```

To learn more about rebasing, see the [Rewriting History](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) section of the [free online Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book), as well as the [official Linux Kernel Git documentation for `rebase`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html).